# File cannot be read after regex operation (Python)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, io

I am trying out regex operations in Python. However, I am not able to read the file again once I use it for the same.

```
f = codecs.open(filename, 'rU', 'utf-8')
#print f.read() works here

#printing the year
year = re.search(r'Popularity in (\w+)',f.read())
print year.group(1)

#now, this returns nothing !
print f.read()
```

I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You're at the end of the file stream so there's nothing left to read. When reading files consider using the `with` statement to close resources.

Comment: How can you close resources with `with` statement ? I am aware of `f.close()` only.

Comment: Here's an example: `with open('myfile.txt') as f:` then indent and do all your file operations. When the interpreter leaves the scope defined by the indented region below the `with` statement, it will close the file for you. For more info: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `f.read()`, the file object will step over all lines and as file objects are generators, it will remember where it stopped reading. If you continue reading with calling `f.read()` again, the file object will continue reading where it left, i.e. at the end of the file. By calling `f.seek(0)` you will reset the position in the file and you can read the file again. In your case it may make more sense to save the content of the file in variable, which can be accessed multiple times.

```
file_content = f.read()
year = re.search(r'Popularity in (\w+)', file_content)
print year.group(1)

print file_content
```

or

```
year = re.search(r'Popularity in (\w+)', f.read())
print year.group(1)

f.seek(0)  # reset the file read position
print f.read()
```

I would choose the first option.

Comment: Yes, the first option makes more sense because otherwise I would have to reset the the position after every regex operation. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Add `f.seek(0)` before the second read. Once the file was readed completely, the pointer comes to the file end. Now you have to move the pointer up(ie, file start) . In-order to do this, we have to add `fileobject.seek(0)`